# Will a convergent Double Sequence be bounded also?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

A convergent Double Sequence will be bounded also.

My Attempt: I think the statement is not true.

Counter Example :  $a_{1n} = n$,
                $ a_{mn} = 1/m + 1/n$ for all $m \geq 2$

lim$_{m,n \to \infty} a_{mn} =0$  But   $ a_{mn}$ is not bounded .

Have I gone wrong anywhere? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't work, $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} a_{mn} = 0$ can be defined as for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that if $m+n>N$, then
$$|a_{mn}| < \epsilon $$
and this is violated when $m=1,n=n$. Its not the same thing as $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} a_{mn}$, for which your $a_{mn}$ does give a value of $0$

Comment: What is the definition of $\lim_{m,n\to \infty }a_{mn}$ ?

Comment: for every $e > 0$ there  exists a natural number $N$ such that  $|a_{mn} - l| < e$ for all $m ,n  > N$..@zhw.

Comment: Then Can you please tell me will the sequence $1 /m + 1/n$ be convergent or not?@CalvinKhor

Comment: I took help from this site http://mathonline.wikidot.com/double-sequences-of-real-numbers-review...@zhw.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether the statement is correct or wrong? I am still waiting for your reply..@zhw.

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204124/what-is-the-definition-of-double-sequence-a-mn-being-convergent-to-l?noredirect=1#comment6592661_3204124   also@CalvinKhor

Comment: it is convergent