# Does existence of both double limits imply boundedness?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, compactness, double-sequence

Let $(a_{n,m})_{n\in\mathbb N,\,m\in \mathbb N}$ be a double sequence taking real values. We may consider different types of limit:

1. $\lim_{n\to\infty,\,m\to\infty} a_{n,m} = l_1\in\mathbb R\,$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_\epsilon\in\mathbb N$ such that $\min(n,m)>N_\epsilon\Rightarrow|a_{n,m}-l_1|<\epsilon\,$;
2. $\lim_{||(n,m)||\to\infty} a_{n,m} = l_2\in\mathbb R\,$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_\epsilon\in\mathbb N$ such that $\max(n,m)>N_\epsilon\Rightarrow|a_{n,m}-l_2|<\epsilon\,$;
3. $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lim_{m\to\infty} a_{n,m}) = l_3\in\mathbb R$ if for every $\epsilon>0$

   - *for every* $n\in\mathbb N$ there exist $L_n\in\mathbb R$ and $M_{\epsilon,n}\in\mathbb N$ such that $m>M_{\epsilon,n}\Rightarrow|a_{n,m}-L_n|<\epsilon\,$
   - there exist $N_\epsilon\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>N_\epsilon\Rightarrow|L_n-l_3|<\epsilon$ ;
4. $\lim_{m\to\infty}(\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,m}) = l_4\in\mathbb R$ if for every $\epsilon>0$

   - *for every* $m\geq M_\epsilon$ there exist $\Lambda_m\in\mathbb R$ and $N_{\epsilon,m}\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>N_{\epsilon,m}\Rightarrow|a_{n,m}-\Lambda_m|<\epsilon\,$
   - there exist $M_\epsilon\in\mathbb N$ such that $m>M_\epsilon\Rightarrow|\Lambda_m-l_4|<\epsilon$ ;

In
[What is the definition of double sequence $a_{mn}$ being convergent to $l$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204124/what-is-the-definition-of-double-sequence-a-mn-being-convergent-to-l?noredirect=1&lq=1)
it is shown that convergence 1. does not ensure that the sequence $(a_{n,m})_{n,m\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded.

Convergence 2. should be enough to guarantee that $(a_{n,m})_{n,m\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded.

**My question is :** convergence 3. together with convergence 4. (with $l_3\neq l_4$ in general) suffice to guarantee $(a_{n,m})_{n,m\in\mathbb N}$ bounded?

Notice that in the definitions of double limits 3. and 4. I have assumed convergence of the first limit *for every value* of the second index, in order to avoid problems similar to those appearing here [What is the definition of double sequence $a_{mn}$ being convergent to $l$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204124/what-is-the-definition-of-double-sequence-a-mn-being-convergent-to-l?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$a_{n,m}=\begin{cases}
n,&\text{if }n=m\\
0,&\text{otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$

then each row limit is $0$ and each column limit is $0$, but the double sequence is unbounded.

$$\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
\color{red}0&0&0&0&0&\ldots&0\\
0&\color{red}1&0&0&0&\ldots&0\\
0&0&\color{red}2&0&0&\ldots&0\\
0&0&0&\color{red}3&0&\ldots&0\\
0&0&0&0&\color{red}4&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\color{red}\ddots&\vdots\\\hline
0&0&0&0&0&\ldots&0
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I have a double sequence such that limits $l_3$ and $l_4$ exist and are finite but $l_3\neq l_4$, what can be a strategy to prove that the sequence is bounded? (knowing that limit 2. cannot exists)

Comment: @tituf: You’re welcome. You’d need to know more about the double sequence. Note that we could change all of the zeroes below the diagonal to $1$ and get $\ell_3=0\ne 1=\ell_4$ without really changing the nature of the problem presented by examples like this one. At the moment I don’t see any condition that would ensure boundedness that isn’t just some restatement of boundedness.