# Calculating $\large \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x+1)-f(x)) dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Given $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 2$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = 1$, what's the following equal to:
$\large \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x+1)-f(x)) dx $

I know that $\large \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx $ is exists if and only if both $\large \int\limits_{0}^\infty dx $ and $\large \int\limits_{-\infty}^0 dx $ exist.Then I tried splitting the integrand into two but I realized that I can't do it since the limit of the given function isn't zero.

Any hints?

Comment: Suppose you knew an antiderivative of $f$ – let's say, $\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+C$. What could you say about $\int_{-m}^n(f(x+1)-f(x))\,dx$?

Comment: Add the integrals from $n$ to $n+1$. Make a change of variable in each of these integrals. You will get a  telescoping sum .

Comment: I see where you are trying to go, but I'm stuck

Comment: Any thoughts about what other users have posted, Harry?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responsive.

Answer (score 2):

First, if one were to be really pedantic, there exists a bounded Lebesgue-measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 2$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = 1$ but such that $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ is not Lebesgue-integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's instead suppose that $f$ is Riemann-integrable over every bounded real interval, and we are trying to show that if $N_i$ and $M_j$ are sequences that tend to $\infty$, then the double sequence $\displaystyle\int_{-M_j}
^{N_i} (f(x+1)-f(x))\, \text{d}x$ converges to a limit. If you don't know what it means for a double sequence to converge to a limit, see the accepted answer in

[What is the definition of double sequence $a_{mn}$ being convergent to $l$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204124/what-is-the-definition-of-double-sequence-a-mn-being-convergent-to-l)

Now, for $N_i$ and $M_j$ both positive, we have

$\displaystyle\int_{-M_j}
^{N_i} (f(x+1)-f(x))\, \text{d}x$

$=\displaystyle\int_{-M_j}
^{N_i} (f(x+1))\, \text{d}x-\int_{-M_j}
^{N_i} f(x)\, \text{d}x$

$=\displaystyle\int_{-M_j+1}
^{N_i+1} f(x)\, \text{d}x-\int_{-M_j}
^{N_i} f(x)\, \text{d}x$

$=\displaystyle\int_{N_i}
^{N_i+1} f(x)\, \text{d}x-\int_{-M_j}
^{-M_j+1} f(x)\, \text{d}x$

which of course tends to $2-1=1$.